# Handling stock to either going below stock or preventing user to buy

Tags: database, stock

I just want your suggestions on how to handle stock availability of products.

PRODUCT NAME: Item x
PRODUCT STOCK: 5

CASE: 
Customer A adds 3 item x into his basket but still hasn't purchase the item. Same time customer B buys all 5 of item x so the stock becomes 0 for the item but the customer A is not aware of it.

QUESTION: 
How should I handle this case? Is there a common or standard way to handle such case like stopping customer A buying the item which was already in his basket by saying "sorry this item is out of stock now"? Or is it just matter of how you want to handle it.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there any stock management design pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836487/is-there-any-stock-management-design-pattern)